# Problem connecting to wss server written in C# and SuperWebSocket from Angular 9 client

Tags: c#, angular, ssl

I have a WebSocket server in C# using SuperWebSocket :

```
var lServer = new LiveWebServer();
ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig();
config.Ip = "any";
config.Port = 444;
config.Security = "tls";
config.Certificate = new CertificateConfig
{
  FilePath = @"C:\Certificate\radar.io.-cert.pfx",
  ClientCertificateRequired = false
};
lServer.NewMessageReceived += LServer_NewMessageReceived;
var result = lServer.Setup(config);
```

and my Angular client:

```
const url = 'wss://radar.io:444';
this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
```

I can easily connect to my server from a .net client but get the following error when connecting from Angular client:

WebSocket connection to 'wss://radar.io:444/' failed:
connect @ main.js:16612

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: can you check your security settings like port settings or any chrome extension you have downloaded

Comment: I don't have any extensions on chrome. the problem is that I cant connect to my wss websocket from other applications. only my .net core api can connect to it.